# My swift code performs a segue when even if it shows that an error is occuring in the firebase login

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is my code, the first part (Auth.auth.signin) is authenticating with `Firebase` if the emailId and password is correct. After that, if incorrect, it print incorrect. This part does show up in the console. However, the code performs the `segue` even though it is not supposed to. Why is this?

```
@IBAction func loginPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    //TODO: Log in the user
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailTextfield.text!, password: passwordTextfield.text!) { (user, error) in
        print(error!)

        if(error != nil || user == nil){
            print("incorrect signin")
        }
        else{
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToChat", sender: self)
            print("Login was good")

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use else if(error == nil && user != nil)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have assigned `Segue` from button. Remove the older one and create new `Segue` like shown below:

[image]

And add identifier for `Segue`.

Answer (score 2):

You have done segue from your button. Remove it and add Segue from View Controller to view controller.